# All Array-Elements edited while editing just one

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, hashmap

I'm a noob in java and just starting out.

I have this problem: there is a `boolean[]` stored in the `HashMap`

```
HashMap <String,boolean[]> calendar = new HashMap<String, boolean[]>();
```

So every element of `intervalls` should be `true`, but console says that all are `false` when running `setFree(1, false, "01010001");`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Calendar {
    
    int numberOfIntervalls = 12;
    
    HashMap <String,boolean[]> calendar = new HashMap<String, boolean[]>();
    
    public Calendar() {
            
    }
    
    private void summonDay(String _day) {
        /*
         * Der String setzt sich nach dem Prinzip ddmmyyyy zusammen.
         */
        boolean[] intervalls = new boolean[numberOfIntervalls];
        System.out.print("Summoned " + _day + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntervalls; i++) {
            intervalls[i] = true;
            System.out.print(intervalls[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(".");
        calendar.put(_day, intervalls); 
        
    }
    
    public boolean isFree(int _time, String _day) {
        int time = _time - 1;
        if(!calendar.containsKey(_day)) {
            System.out.println("free");
            return true;
        }
        boolean[] _intervalls = calendar.get(_day);
        _intervalls = calendar.get(_day);
        for (int i = 0; i <calendar.get(_day).length; i++) {
            System.out.print(calendar.get(_day)[i] + ", ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _intervalls.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(_intervalls[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(_intervalls[time]);
        
        return _intervalls[time];
    }
    
    public void setFree(int _time, boolean _free, String _day) {
        int time = _time - 1;
        boolean[] intervalls = new boolean[numberOfIntervalls];
        if(calendar.containsKey(_day)) {
            System.out.println("Contains " + _day);
            intervalls = calendar.get(_day);
            intervalls[time] = _free;
            System.out.println(intervalls[time]);
            if(allElementsTheSameBool(intervalls) && _free)
                calendar.remove(_day);
            else
            calendar.put(_day, intervalls); 
        }else {
            if(!_free) {
                summonDay(_day);
                intervalls[time] = _free;
                calendar.put(_day, intervalls); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------");
        for (int i = 0; i <calendar.get(_day).length; i++) {
            System.out.print(calendar.get(_day)[i] + ", ");
        }
        
    }
    
    public boolean allElementsTheSameBool(boolean[] intervalls) {
        if (intervalls.length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            boolean first = intervalls[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < intervalls.length; i++) {
                if (intervalls[i] != first) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public int getNumberOfIntervalls() {
        return numberOfIntervalls;
    }
    public boolean isLeapYear(int _year) {
        /*
         *     Schaltjahre müssen durch 4 teilbar sein.
    Ist das Jahr auch durch 100 teilbar, ist es kein Schaltjahr, es sei denn...
    ...das Jahr ist ebenfalls durch 400 teilbar – dann ist es ein Schaltjahr.
         */
        if(_year%4 == 0) {
            if(_year%100 == 0) {
                if(_year%400 == 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void toTest(/* insert Parameters*/) {

    }
    
}
```

(All the `System.out.println();` are just for debugging.)
I really have no clue which line sets it all `false`...

Comment: Post the entire code please.

Comment: Sadly, it's extremely hard to tell what your code is trying to do. It would help if you stripped it down to the core functionality that is not working for you.

Comment: @michalwa it's the setFree()-method. I had only this method as code before.

Comment: Are you calling the `summonDay()` before the `setFree()`?

Comment: Yeah, it's alright. Sorry, I've confused myself. :)

Comment: @fjsv I'm calling summonDay() only in setFree().

Comment: I've tested your code and as long as you follow that order you should be fine. Keep in mind that if you create a `boolean`, by default it is false. Maybe that was the issue. But with the `summonDay()` the array should be properly filled.

Comment: @michalwa no problem :-)

Comment: @fjsv so you tested it and it works?

Comment: I don't know exactly the expected behaviour, but from what I could gather, if the issue is having a day with only `false` in the `intervals[]`, has long as you start by "filling" the day with `true` it should work.

Comment: @fjsv I use `setFree(1, false, "01010001");` and ` for (int i = 0; i <calendar.get(_day).length; i++) {
   System.out.print(calendar.get(_day)[i] + ", ");
  }` only gives `false`s

Comment: Check My answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing to keep in mind is that something like this:

```
boolean[] intervals = new boolean[3];
```

Will create an array with: `[false, false, false]`. It seems that the problem may be about this.

I've tested your code and it is not 100% clear what is the starting point, but if you run the `summonDay()` before the `setFree()`. In order to "fill" the day with intervals, I think you get the expected result.

What I did was:

```
static int numberOfIntervalls = 12;

static Map<String,boolean[]> calendar = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    summonDay("01010001");
    setFree(3, false, "01010001");
}

private static void summonDay(String _day) {
    boolean[] intervals = new boolean[numberOfIntervalls];
    System.out.print("Summoned " + _day + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntervalls; i++) {
        intervals[i] = true;
        System.out.print(intervals[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(".");
    calendar.put(_day, intervals);

}

public static void setFree(int _time, boolean _free, String _day) {
    int time = _time - 1;
    boolean[] intervals = new boolean[numberOfIntervalls];

    if(calendar.containsKey(_day)) {
        System.out.println("Contains " + _day);
        intervals = calendar.get(_day);
        intervals[time] = _free;
        System.out.println(intervals[time]);
        if(allElementsTheSameBool(intervals) && _free)
            calendar.remove(_day);
        else
            calendar.put(_day, intervals);
    }else {
        if(!_free) {
            summonDay(_day);
            intervals[time] = false;
            calendar.put(_day, intervals);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("-------");

    for (int i = 0; i <calendar.get(_day).length; i++) {
        System.out.print(calendar.get(_day)[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

If you check the `main()` you have there both methods being called

And my output was:

```
Summoned 01010001 true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, .
Contains 01010001
false
-------
true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So it started with 12 `true`s and after the `setFree()` was called it freed the third interval.

It seems that the problem is that you are missing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntervalls; i++) {
    intervals[i] = true;
    System.out.print(intervals[i] + ", ");
}
```

When creating a `day` and that is the reason behind the all `false` `intervals`.